# Find the covariance matrix given its eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

Given the point cloud below and that the ratio of its eigenvalues is 3, could someone guide me to find the covariance matrix of the point-cloud below?

What I figured so far:
- From the diagram, I think the two eigenvectors should be [-1, 1] (along greatest variance) and [1, 1] (orthogonal to [-1, 1]).

- And using the Eigenvector formula, Ax = λx, I should get the following equations:

```
a) A[-1 1]' = 3[-1 1]'
b) A[1 1]' = 1[1 1]'
```

Is my thought-process correct? If yes, how should I carry on further?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently a uniform distribution over a rectangular region whose dimensions are not specified. Turn the region around the origin by $-45^{\circ}$.
If this is the case then the distribution will look like this:

[image]
So, we have two independent random variables both uniformly distributed over $[-a,a]$ and $[-b,b]$, respectively.

The covariance matrix is easy to calculate now:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{a^2}3&0\\
0&\frac{b^2}3\end{bmatrix}.$$

The eigenvectors are 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\
0\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{bmatrix}\ 0\\
1\end{bmatrix}$$
and te corresponding eigenvalues are $$\frac{a^2}3\text{ and } \frac{b^2}3.$$

Utilizing the fact that the ratio of the eigenvalues is $3$ we can tell that the covariance matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{a^2}3&0\\
0&a^2\end{bmatrix}.$$

But this is the rotated covariance matrix. We have to turne back the experiment by $45^{\circ}$. The rotation matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}.$$

So, the covariance matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{a^2}3&0\\
0&a^2\end{bmatrix}=a^2\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{3\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{3\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}.$$

$a$ is still unknown. Notice that only one equation was givan and there were two unknowns.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the clear logic. Please bear with me for my 2 follow-up questions: If the covariance matrix is  \begin{bmatrix} x^2 & xy \\ xy & y^2 \end{bmatrix}, then (a) why do we need to divide both x^2 and y^2 by 3 at the very beginning and (b) why is xy = 0?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the above is the answer only for the specific case given in the question.  Isn't there a general formula for constructing a covariance matrix from knowledge of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a more general answer is as follows:  Given the eigenvector matrix **E** (with eigenvectors as columns) and the eigenvalue matrix ${\mathbf{\Lambda}}$, where the diagonal elements are the scalar eigenvalues $\lambda$ and the off-diagonal elements are zero, then the covariance matrix **S** is given by the matrix product

**S** = **E** ${\mathbf{\Lambda}}$ **E**$^{\rm T}$